# login.jsp not found after uploading to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

Since i have changed my authentication provider (migrate SSO authentication), in my spring boot project -
I get the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.login_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
```

~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar!/:8.5.16]

Any ideas? Please assist

Comment: have you configured security group correctly ?

Comment: If you mean the roles that defines what your permissions to get URLs, so yes.. but to get the login form you don't have to have no role (maybe ROLE_ANONYMOUS only, which spring creates by default)
It works for me on locally, but not on AWS server